# PostgreSQL replication - how to update LSN after reading with pg_recvlogical and wal2json? (without superuser)

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.5, wal

I am trying to implement a regular incremental changes dump for our PostgreSQL 9.5 database.

I have opted for WAL, the `wal2json` plugin and `pg_recvlogical`.
All works somehow, except for one thing:

When all data are read, `pg_recvlogical` simply goes silent. There is no way to tell it to quit after some time without changes, right? So I terminate it with `kill -2` (SIGINT), which gives me

```
pg_recvlogical: unexpected termination of replication stream:
```

When I want next batch of changes, the replication slot starts at the same position as before, i.e. the entries are sent again.

**How can I tell PostgreSQL that for some slot, I want set the replication position to the current position of the client?**

There are 2 functions that seem to do that,

- `SELECT * FROM pg_replication_origin_advance(node_name text, pos pg_lsn)`
- `SELECT * FROM pg_replication_origin_progress(node_name text, flush bool)`

However, I am not sure what to pass as parameters. The [manual doesn't tell](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-REPLICATION). What's node_name? And for the position, all that `wal2json` gives me is `xid`.

**Update:** I can use `pg_replication_origin_advance("sas2json", "28/160E2250")`, see my answer. **However**, when I try it:

> ERROR:  only superusers can query or manipulate replication origins

And this is in Amazon RDS. And I can't have SUPERUSER - that's an AWS policy.

Any other way to set the LSN position?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I can enable `-o include-lsn=true` for `wal2json`. With that, it starts giving me

```
{"xid":48311,"nextlsn":"28/160E2250", ...
```

So I can use `nextlsn` to call

```
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_origin_advance("sas2json", "28/160E2250")
```

where the first parameter is the replication slot.

While this anwsers my original question, I need a solution that doesn't need SUPERUSER - if there's any.

Comment: Hey Ondra, did you encounter any problems while advancing the LSN by yourself? I'm mainly asking about situations where there are long transactions still in progress while you're moving the pointer (although I'm not entirely sure if this is a likely scenario).

Comment: @martez, sorry - I don't remember after 5 years :)  I'm now on CockroachDB which works differently.

Comment: hehe, no worries. thanks for coming back to this comment!